# How to bind menu and sub menu and subsubmenu using repeater in asp.net c# with bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, navigationbar

I'd like to have my Bootstrap menu automatically drop down on hover, rather than having to click the menu title. I'd also like to lose the little arrows next to the menu titles.play it as menu but it is showing a list.

My code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server ID=" rptmainmenuOnItemDataBound="menu_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, " url ") %>">
                <%# Eval("menutext") %>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptsubmenu" OnItemDataBound="rptsubmenu_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class="dr">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%# Eval(" url ") %>">
                                <%# Eval("menutext") %>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptsubsubmenu">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please add your code you tried so far.

Comment: <asp:Repeater runat="server ID="rptmainmenuOnItemDataBound="menu_ItemDataBound"    > <ItemTemplate>
 <div class="">
<a class= "dropdown-item" href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>"><%# Eval("menutext") %></a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<asp:Repeater runat="server"  ID="rptsubmenu" OnItemDataBound="rptsubmenu_ItemDataBound"  >
<ItemTemplate>
<li class="dr"><a class="dropdown-item" href="<%# Eval("url") %>"><%# Eval("menutext") %></a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<asp:Repeater runat="server"  ID="rptsubsubmenu" >
<ItemTemplate>

Comment: You should add to the question by editing the question so that others can set it.